# Netbeans is not getting installed in my Mac, it says JDK not found, though JDK is installed in the same

Tags: java, netbeans

Error: Failure while executing the commands mentioned below:-

`/usr/bin/sudo -E -- env LOGNAME=ajaygautam USER=ajaygautam USERNAME=ajaygautam /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /usr/local/Caskroom/netbeans/8.2/NetBeans\ 8.2.pkg -target /` exited with 1.

Here's the output:
installer: Error - NetBeans IDE cannot be installed. Java (JRE) found on your computer but JDK 8 or newer is required. Please download and install the latest update of JDK 8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and restart NetBeans installation.

Would someone in tracing out the issue above? I'm not able to install NetBeans 8.2 package in my Mac.

Comment: try running java -version error once JAVA_HOME variable is set along with proper JAVA_HOME/bin value in path

Comment: Based on the error, you've not installed the **"Java Software Development Kit"** or JDK for short, you've installed the **"Java Runtime Environment"** or JRE for short

Comment: what you mean when i do java -version it shows 
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: hi! How did you fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem... nothing working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually, `java_home` is in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home
```

but in my case, `java_home` was in the next location i.e

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java_home
```

- I deleted my java_home from `/usr/libexec/java_home` by root user
- added new `java_home` in `/usr/libexec` by following command

  ```
  sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java_home /usr/libexec/.
  ```

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem and could to fix it with brew.

firstly install java JDK https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html then run this in your terminal:

```
brew install netbeans
```

it will install the latest version of netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Download OpenJDK from [Archived OpenJDK GA Releases](https://jdk.java.net/archive/).

This will give you a file such as `openjdk-9.0.4_osx-x64_bin.tar`. Extract the tar file and copy it to the correct place in your machine.

```
tar -xf openjdk-9.0.4_osx-x64_bin.tar
sudo cp -r jdk-12.0.2.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

Now you can run the Netbeans installer.

Answer (score -1):

i just install using brew

```
brew install netbeans
```

and now i can use the latest 12.4

Answer (score -2):

*The following steps are used to install **NetBeans** on **MacOS**:-*

**1) Download the Latest version**

In order to install NetBeans on MacOS, we have to download the latest version of NetBeans by visiting its official website I.e. https://netbeans.org/downloads/

**2) Mount the disk image file**

The dmg file which is downloaded from the official website of NetBeans is to be mounted to an installer. This can be done with the following command:

> $ hdiutil mount Downloads/netbeans-8.2-macosx.dmg

**3) Install the file**

The file is mounted to the volumes directory which contains a package file (.pkg) which is installable by using the installer command. The command needs superuser privileges for which, sudo is used.

> $ sudo installer -pkg Volumes/ NetBeans\ 8.2/NetBeans\ 8.2.pkg -target /

The file will be installed to the target root which is mentioned while installing the file.

**4) Unmount the file**

After the completion of installation process, we need to unmount the installer. This can be done by using the option Unmount with hdiutil command.

> $ hdiutil unmount /Volumes/NetBeans\ 8.2

Well, we have done with the installation process of NetBeans 8.2 on MacOS.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, it seems that your question at SO is totally different than what you're trying to say. I would suggest you to edit your question properly so that we can have better & clear understanding of your issue.

Comment: Do modify your question referring to the screenshot what you had given in the above comments. The current question doesn't seem to be proper in accordance with your problem.

Comment: I have modified my answer completely. Please follow the mentioned the process step-by-step & do let me know if you face any challenges in doing the same!

Comment: i got this error installer: invalid option NetBeans 8.2/NetBeans 8.2.pkg

Comment: when i write export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) in my bash_profile file i got error like this -bash: /usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory and also am unable to install any java software it shows jdk is missing. hope this might help me :(

Comment: Did you follow the steps what I've mentioned in the answer?

Comment: yes, i got this error installer: invalid option NetBeans 8.2/NetBeans 8.2.pkg – BIram Firi 17 mins ago

Comment: Please do post your Terminal screenshot in the question so that it would be clear to me. By the by, at which step did you face that error?

Answer (score -3):

For some reason, some Netbeans versions for Mac OS do not detect the JDK contained in JRE. For proper installation and running the application, you must have *Java for Mac OS* installed previously. https://www.java.com/es/download/

Answer (score -4):

Install The Lates Version ONLY which is 12.1 as of now!

https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb121/nb121.html

Comment: This is NOT a solution. Some people might need exactly the 8.2 version (which as far as I know, was the last one offering a full, simple one-click installation of the web development environment, including a pre-installed Tomcat for easy, integrated development, good e.g. for beginners).